# How to uninstall gnome-bluetooth dependancies?

Tags: apt, dependencies

As you can see below, I installed (and then deleted) gnome-bluetooth on my Debian Xfce desktop. It's come with a lot of librairies and `autoremove` doesn't get rid of them.

Is there an automatic way to uninstall everything `gnome-bluetooth` added?

```
Start-Date: 2015-05-14  11:38:36
Commandline: apt-get install gnome-bluetooth
Install: libtotem-plparser18:amd64 (3.10.3-1, automatic), cracklib-runtime:amd64 (2.9.2-1, automatic), apg:amd64 (2.2.3.dfsg.1-2, automatic), gnome-online-accounts:amd64 (3.14.2-1, automatic), mousetweaks:amd64 (3.12.0-1, automatic), libmediaart-1.0-0:amd64 (0.7.0-2, automatic), libibus-1.0-5:amd64 (1.5.9-1, automatic), librygel-server-2.4-2:amd64 (0.24.2-1+b1, automatic), libcolord-gtk1:amd64 (0.1.25-1.1+b1, automatic), librygel-renderer-2.4-2:amd64 (0.24.2-1+b1, automatic), libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1:amd64 (0.2.0-1, automatic), libgnomekbd-common:amd64 (3.6.0-1, automatic), libcrack2:amd64 (2.9.2-1, automatic), libquvi7:amd64 (0.4.1-3, automatic), libapache2-mod-dnssd:amd64 (0.6-3.1, automatic), libgnomekbd8:amd64 (3.6.0-1, automatic), libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.14.2-1, automatic), libgweather-3-6:amd64 (3.14.1-1, automatic), gnome-control-center:amd64 (3.14.4-1, automatic), libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64 (3.14.0-2, automatic), librygel-core-2.4-2:amd64 (0.24.2-1+b1, automatic), libdleyna-core-1.0-3:amd64 (0.4.0-1, automatic), realmd:amd64 (0.15.1-1+b2, automatic), libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3:amd64 (0.10.2-1, automatic), rygel:amd64 (0.24.2-1+b1, automatic), libgrilo-0.2-1:amd64 (0.2.11-2, automatic), libpwquality1:amd64 (1.2.3-1, automatic), libgweather-common:amd64 (3.14.1-1, automatic), gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 (3.14.2-3, automatic), libquvi-scripts:amd64 (0.4.21-2, automatic), gkbd-capplet:amd64 (3.6.0-1, automatic), libgupnp-av-1.0-2:amd64 (0.12.7-1, automatic), libgeocode-glib0:amd64 (3.14.0-1, automatic), libpwquality-common:amd64 (1.2.3-1, automatic), libwacom-common:amd64 (0.8-1, automatic), gnome-bluetooth:amd64 (3.14.0-2), libnss-myhostname:amd64 (0.3-9, automatic), colord:amd64 (1.2.1-1+b2, automatic), apache2-bin:amd64 (2.4.12-2, automatic), libwacom2:amd64 (0.8-1, automatic), dleyna-server:amd64 (0.4.0-1, automatic), gnome-user-share:amd64 (3.14.0-2, automatic), gnome-control-center-data:amd64 (3.14.4-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2015-05-14  11:38:46

Start-Date: 2015-05-14  11:45:45
Commandline: apt-get remove gnome-bluetooth
Remove: gnome-bluetooth:amd64 (3.14.0-2), gnome-user-share:amd64 (3.14.0-2)
End-Date: 2015-05-14  11:45:48

Start-Date: 2015-05-14  11:46:02
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Remove: libapache2-mod-dnssd:amd64 (0.6-3.1), apache2-bin:amd64 (2.4.12-2)
End-Date: 2015-05-14  11:46:03


Start-Date: 2015-05-14  11:47:47
Commandline: apt-get purge gnome-bluetooth
Purge: gnome-bluetooth:amd64 ()
End-Date: 2015-05-14  11:47:47
```

Comment: @Pandya of course I tried but I did forget to put the log. It's done now!

Comment: Really `autoremove` is not doing?! What is the output of `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: @Pandya you have it on the log report for apt in my message.

Comment: How about `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends autoremove`?

Comment: @StephenKitt Nothing removed. I believe `--no-install-recommends` is for installation only.

Comment: Quite possibly... I'm guessing that some other package you have installed recommends the packages installed for `gnome-bluetooth`, so I was hoping `autoremove` with `--no-install-recommends` wouldn't consider them as preventing removal. What does `aptitude why cracklib-runtime` say?